# Finding Subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to find all the subgroups of the alternating group, A4; however, I am not sure how to solve this problem efficiently. Is there a better way than listing out all of the subgroups? Thanks!

Comment: You might start by finding all of the elements with order $2$ and order $3$. From this you can immediately determine all subgroups of these orders, and it's also easy to reason about subgroups of order $4$ (hint: there's no element of order $4$). So that just leaves order $6$ to consider.

Comment: A4 does not have a subgroup of order 6. I'm concerned about the subgroups of order 8, and 12.

Comment: $A_4$ has order 12, so the subgroup of order 12 is just $A_4$ itself. It can't have a subgroup of order 8, because 8 is not a divisor of 12. You are correct that there is no subgroup of order 6, but can you prove this?

Comment: Whoops, forgot to divide n! by 2. For subgroups of order 4, do we just take the (_,_) (_,_) elements? For 2 and 3, it should be easy since they are cyclic by their prime orders.